# Why are these two definitions of the left-adjoint to $u^p\colon PShv(D)\to PShv(C)$ equivalent?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Suppose $u\colon C\to D$ is a functor between categories. Then there is a functor
$$
u^p\colon PShv(D)\to PShv(C)
$$
between the associated presheaf categories by precomposition with $u$ as it is explained in [the stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00VC).

One may construct a left-adjoint $u_p$ to $u^p$ in two ways:

**First**, one sets for $F\in PShv(C)$ and $V\in D$
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
u_p(F)(V)&=&\underset{(YU\to F)\in \int_CF}{\operatorname{colim}} Y(u(U))(V)\\
         &=&\underset{(YU\to F)\in \int_CF}{\operatorname{colim}} Hom_{D}(V,uU)
\end{array}
$$
where $Y$ denotes the Yoneda embedding of $C$ (resp. $D$) into the $PShv(C)$ (resp. $PShv(D)$) and where $\int_CF$ is the *category of elements* of $F$ whose objects are natural transformations $YU\to F$ for some $U\in C$ and whose morphisms are given by $Yf\colon YU\to YU'$ for some morphisms $f\colon U\to U'$ of $C$ fitting into a commutative triangle **over** $F$. This construction of the left-adjoint is a *left Kan extension*. One has given the functor $u$ from representables and prolongs it universally to a functor from the whole category of presheaves.

**Secondly**, according to [the stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00VC), the left-adjoint $v^p$ (I just temporarily write $v^p$ for $u^p$ to distinguish from the first definition) $u_p$ is given for $F\in PShv(C)$ and $V\in D$ by
$$
v_p(F)(V)= \underset{(V\to uU)\in (I_V^u)^{opp}}{\operatorname{colim}} F(U)
$$
where $I_V^u$ is the category whose objects are morphisms $V\to u(U)$ in $D$ for some $U\in C$ and whose morphisms are given by $uf\colon uU\to uU'$ for some morphisms $f\colon U\to U'$ of $C$ fitting into a commutative triangle **under** $V$.

Of course, one may say that a left adjoint to a given functor $u^p$ is unique up to natural isomorphism of functors but my question is:

> Is there a concrete natural isomorphism between $u_p$ and $v_p$? If yes, how is it constructed and how to show that it is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Concerning $v_p$:***

For any ${\mathscr F}\in\text{PreShv}({\mathcal C})$ we have $$(\ast)\quad\underset{\alpha\in {\mathscr F}U}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}(-,U)\xrightarrow{\cong} {\mathscr F}.$$
$$(\alpha\in{\mathscr F}U,\beta: U^{\prime}\to U)\longmapsto {\mathscr F}(\beta)(\alpha)\in{\mathscr F}(U^{\prime}).$$
Plugging this into your second description gives
$$(\dagger)\quad v_p({\mathscr F})(V) := \underset{V\to uU}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathscr F}(U)\cong\underset{V\to uU}{\text{colim}}\ \underset{\alpha\in {\mathscr F}U^{\prime}}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}(U,U^{\prime}).$$

***Concerning $u_p$:***

Note that for any $V\in{\mathcal D}$ there is a canonical isomorphism
$$\underset{V\to u U^{\prime}}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}(U^{\prime},U)\xrightarrow{\cong} {\mathcal D}(V,uU), $$
$$(\alpha: V\to u U^{\prime}, \beta: U^{\prime}\to U)\ \ \longmapsto\ \  {\mathscr F}(\beta)\circ\alpha$$
$$\gamma: V\to uU\ \ \longmapsto \ \ (\alpha := \gamma, \beta := \text{id}_{U=U^{\prime}});$$
This is a special case of $(\ast)$ applied to the presheaf ${\mathscr G}: U\mapsto{\mathcal D}(V,uU)$ on ${\mathcal C}^{\text{opp}}$: An element of ${\mathscr G}$ is a pair $(U^{\prime},\alpha)$ with $U^{\prime}\in\text{Obj}({\mathcal C}^{\text{opp}})=\text{Obj}({\mathcal C})$ and $\alpha\in{\mathscr G}(U^{\prime})={\mathcal D}(V,uU^{\prime})$, so $${\mathcal D}(V,u(-))\quad\cong\quad\underset{V\to uU^{\prime}}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}^{\text{opp}}(-,U^{\prime})=\underset{V\to uU^{\prime}}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}(U^{\prime},-).$$
Using this in your description of $u_p$, you get 
$$(\ddagger)\quad u_p({\mathscr F})(V) = \underset{\alpha\in {\mathscr F}U}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal D}(V,uU)\cong\underset{\alpha\in{\mathscr F}U}{\text{colim}}\ \underset{V\to u U^{\prime}}{\text{colim}}\ {\mathcal C}(U^{\prime},U)$$

***Conclusion:***

Comparing $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$ we see that $v_p$ and $u_p$ are isomorphic by renaming $U$, $U^{\prime}$ and exchanging the colimits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please say a little more on the isomorphism $colim C(U',U)\cong D(V,uU)$ please?

Comment: @jeffrey: Does this make things clearer?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :)